# Thieves cant across different languages

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, rogue, languages

All rogues know thieves cant.

If one rogue in the party is talking to an enemy in a language that an ally rogue in the party does not understand, would the speaking rogue be able to use thieves cant to convey a message to the other rogue who does not know the language being spoken to the enemy?

Would this realistically be possible without raising suspicion from the enemy? How would you as a Dungeon Master handle this situation?

The key thing to note here is that RAW says that thieves cant:

> allows you to hide messages in seemingly normal conversation.

So what happens if said conversation is being spoken in a language that only one of the two rogues understands?

Comment: Some at least related questions: "[Can Thieves' Cant be used across languages?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/132288)" and "[Is Thieves' Cant a language?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/153571)"

Comment: I at least felt your question was a duplicate of the one I've marked, if you feel this is not the case, feel free to explain (or edit in) why that is. That said, it being a duplicate is not a bad thing at all, and is in fact helpful for when people search for answers to this question or something similar

Comment: Nah, you're right. It's basically a duplicate.